# Does github honour Jekyll's "source" variable?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

In an attempt to make my workflow a bit neater, I came across the source tag, which allows me to host my "dev work" in a separate folder than my _site.

This is awesome, but it does not appear to be honoured by Github pages? I feel like I am doing something wrong though, so just wanted to check. I couldn't find much about it online.

In this case, I don't explicitly need github to do it, but it would be great to have this consistent workflow for projects that do rely on github pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GH Pages overrides the  source setting in the Jekyll config file:
https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-build-failures#source-setting

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-pages

Comment: Include the relevant information in your answer and reference the original source. Try to avoid link only answers.

Comment: Thanks Bud! This answers my questions 100%, and will mark it as such. David get's points for giving me a bonus solution!

Thanks guys! *highfives*

(I would upvote you all, but I don't have the reputation yet) :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change **source** or **destination** parameters to version them separately. You can just version them in two different branches from the same repository.

### Why versioning in different branches ?

If you need some plugins (generator, tag, ...) or build tasks (gulp, grunt, ...) that will not run on gh-pages, you will have to publish your Jekyll sources in a branch and your build results in a separate branch.

For a User / Organization site, it will be **master** for the site build, and **sources** (or any name you like) for the code. A User / Organization site will be versioned at github.com/userName/userName.github.io and hosted at http://userName.github.io (or with a custom domain)

For a Project site, it will be **gh-pages** for the site build, and **master** (or any name you like) for the code.
A Project site will be versioned at github.com/userName/projectName and hosted at http://userName.github.io/projectName.

### Steps for User\Organization site

1. create a repository on github (eg: https://github.com/userName/userName.github.io)
2. go to command line and `cd pathTo/yourJekyllSource`
3. `git init`
4. `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git`
5. `jekyll new .` creates your code base
6. in **_config.yml**, set the baseurl parameter to **baseurl: ''**
7. in **.gitignore** add **_site**, it will be versioned in the **gh-pages** branch
8. `jekyll build` will create the **_site** destination folder and build site into it.
9. `git checkout -b sources`
10. `git add -A && git commit -m "jekyll base sources"` commit your source code
11. `git push origin sources` push your sources in the **sources** branch
12. `cd _site`
13. `touch .nojekyll`, this file tells gh-pages that there is no need to process files
14. `git init`
15. `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git`
16. `git checkout master`
17. `git add -A && git commit -m "jekyll first build"` commit your site code
18. `git push origin master`

And your good to go !

Your deploy can be made like this :

```
cd pathTo/yourJekyllSource
jekyll build
git add -A
git commit -m "your commit message"
cd _site
git add -A
git commit -m "your commit message"
```

**Steps for a Project site are [described here](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows#project-repository)** and I've made an **[automation Rakefile](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows/blob/master/Rakefile)**, it can do everything for you from setup to deploy.

Enjoy !

Comment: Okay wait. I ran out of talent reading this, but if what I read is correct:

- I can have the "processed site" in one branch, and
- the development version in a completely different branch?

Omg, I absolutely love that idea. I currently deploy my site to my own server through a POST hook, but I don't love the idea of having EVERYTHING on there, it's a waste of space. 

I'm going to give this a try this afternoon and let you know how it went. You don't perhaps have a repo of your own that I can check out?

Comment: I'm sure that my Rakefile will solve your problem https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows